# How to get post id after successful FB ShareDialog post

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sharer

I am referring "ios 3.5 how to" by Facebook. Here is my code

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params
                        clientState:nil
                            handler:
 ^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
 if(error) {
     // If there's an error show the relevant message
     [self showAlert:[self checkErrorMessage:error]];
 } else {
     // Check if cancel info is returned and log the event
     if (results[@"completionGesture"] &&
         [results[@"completionGesture"] isEqualToString:@"cancel"]) {
         NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
     } else {
         // If the post went through show a success message
         [self showAlert:[self checkPostId:results]];
     }
 }
```

In results I only get didComplete key with value 1. How can I get post_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use dictionary

```
call.dialogData.clientState
```

Answer (score 1):

How about to see this dictionary `call.dialogData.clientState` http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.5/class/FBDialogsData

Comment: I think you're right!
According to FB Documentation:

`clientState = Client JSON state that is passed through to the completion handler for context.`
 
clientState is a property from FBDialogsData, which is a property from FBAppCall.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked the results `NSDictionary`?

Put `NSLog(@"Results Dictionary: %@",results);` inside your second else statement and check the content of this dictionary.

Comment: I did that already i am only getting didComplete in that dictionary :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll only get the post_id returned if the user is logged in to Facebook on your app. That is, if the user has authenticated your app. If the user hasn't authenticated your app, this isn't returned.

So try putting say an FBLoginView, logging in, and seeing if the post_id gets returned.

Comment: it's not! no post_id with login as well, nice try though.

Answer (score 0):

I note that it only getting didComplete on ios5,if you test it on ios6,then can getting both "didComplete" and "completionGesture". It maybe a bug of facebook SDK.